# Load Dropdown values dynamically in Appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a use case where I need to display User's Team Drive names in a drop down, I have done a code to fetch team drive's names for a user but I am not able to load these values in Drop down dynamically.

In Drop down widget "options" tag I am making a function call, which calls server for fetching these data and server returns the values. But the same data is not being reflected.

Here's my snippet,

```javascript
function fetchValues() {
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
      app.closeDialog();  
      setNotificationText(error);
      app.popups.Snackbar.visible = true;
    })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
      // This result has the list of team drive names.
      return result;
    })
    .fetchValues();  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client script function `fetchValues` returns `undefined`, you can test it using dev tools console:

```javascript
console.log(fetchValues());
```

It happens due to async nature of communication between client (browser) and server (you can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)). The easiest and most straight-forward way to fix your current code will be changing your binding to this:

```javascript
fetchValues(@widget);
```

and change your function to this

```javascript
function fetchValues(dropdown) {
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
      ...
    })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
      dropdown.options = result;
    })
    .fetchValues();  
}
```

But in general it doesn't seem to be a right way to populate dropdown's `options` and `names` in App Maker. I would consider reworking this part using [Calculated Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated) or [Custom Properties](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties)